# Adicionar o Firebase ao Projeto Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Fiz tudo o que pede no site do Firebase, mas quando clico em Sync no Gradle dentro do projeto, antes de finalizar ele aparece um ERRO, como podem ver abaixo;
[image: ERRO Gradle Android Studio]

Por favor me ajudem!

Comment: Poderia colocar o erro da imagem como um texto na pergunta?

Comment: Bem vindo Waldécio, por favor, pedimos que [leia este artigo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), edite sua pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com o erro, está faltando dependência no seu `Gradle`. Para resolver o problema, adicione dependências para [bibliotecas básicas necessárias](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) para os serviços que está faltando no início seu `Gradle`. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Logo depois nas suas `dependencies` inclua o `firebase-messaging`. Veja:

```
dependencies {
...
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}
```

Para mais detalhes, veja como [configurar um aplicativo cliente do Firebase Cloud Messaging no Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) e as instrunções básicas do [Google services Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).